# Konsole keyboard shortcut for switching between active Split View?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde-plasma, konsole

The KDE 5 terminal emulator *Konsole* has a great feature *Split View* that allows me to make full use of my big monitor. However, I cannot find a way to use keyboard shortcuts, rather than clicking mouse, to switch between the active views (see: [The Konsole Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/konsole.pdf)). This apparently reduces the work efficiency. Anyone has an idea how to enable this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 32):

What works on version 19.08.2 is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>. You can use up, down, left, right as required.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used to switch between all views including in other tabs. It is like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> of window managers that you can switch between last ones relasing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and using this shortcut again.

Answer (score 10):

the shortcuts are called **Focus (Above|Below|Left|Right) Terminal**. by default they are mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>.
to change these shortcuts, go to **Settings** -> **Configure Keyboard Shortcuts** -> Search for "focus".

Answer (score 7):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> should work to navigate between the Konsole tabs.

Answer (score 0):

`shift` + `tab` worked for me to switch across multiple tabs that are open in an active split-view screen on a Konsole application in CentOS versions > 6.x